# Any way to "pin" something to the bottom for rotation?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a view with a button at the bottom of the portrait screen, when I flip to landscape my  tableview and everything else adjusts fine, but my button at the bottom is now missing. I can't find a property in IB that would allow me to make the position of that button relative to the bottom of the screen, so that if it flips to landscape then it will still be "5 pixels above the bottom" or whatever.

Any thoughts? Is a toolbar the only way to go here? What about for other controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Interface Builder and select the button you wish to anchor to the bottom.  Choose Tools -> Inspector then click the Ruler icon.  In the auto sizing section select the southern most I-Beam.